# JSON issue in Android project

Tags: java, android, json, http

I am messing around with the code from this tutorial: http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/parsing-json-from-url-in-android/

I downloaded the source code and got everything successfully set up in my project. I launched my app and pressed the "Get JSON" button and everything worked.

The URL being used in their tutorial is http://mobisys.in/quicknotify/get_departments.php?company_id=1.

The JSON that comes from that page looks like this:

```
[{"dept":"Mobile","dept_id":"1"},{"dept":"Web","dept_id":"2"}]
```

I wanted to use my own URL so I changed the one that they gave to my own. I also changed the selectors to match the new link.

The new URL is http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2007/export?TYPE=topAdds&W=12&JSON=1 and this is what it returns in a browser:

```
{"version":"1.0","topAdds":{"week":"12","player":[{"percent":"41.65","id":"8827"},{"percent":"36.89","id":"8752"},{"percent":"25.60","id":"0519"},{"percent":"16.35","id":"5730"},{"percent":"14.14","id":"6562"},{"percent":"13.56","id":"7547"},{"percent":"10.34","id":"3869"},{"percent":"9.87","id":"5660"},{"percent":"8.75","id":"7553"},{"percent":"8.36","id":"7084"},{"percent":"8.12","id":"7480"},{"percent":"8.05","id":"4907"},{"percent":"7.10","id":"6616"},{"percent":"6.85","id":"7625"},{"percent":"6.66","id":"3494"},{"percent":"6.56","id":"8117"},{"percent":"6.11","id":"7071"},{"percent":"5.91","id":"4092"},{"percent":"5.86","id":"7399"},{"percent":"5.78","id":"6715"},{"percent":"4.68","id":"4932"},{"percent":"4.49","id":"3969"},{"percent":"4.46","id":"7837"},{"percent":"4.38","id":"7895"},{"percent":"4.24","id":"7021"},{"percent":"4.13","id":"0525"},{"percent":"4.05","id":"5666"},{"percent":"3.86","id":"6528"},{"percent":"3.81","id":"0512"},{"percent":"3.70","id":"3875"},{"percent":"3.68","id":"4984"},{"percent":"3.67","id":"8135"},{"percent":"3.48","id":"5482"},{"percent":"3.32","id":"1653"},{"percent":"3.29","id":"8244"},{"percent":"3.20","id":"0511"},{"percent":"2.76","id":"3369"},{"percent":"2.73","id":"5065"},{"percent":"2.72","id":"6786"},{"percent":"2.70","id":"8326"},{"percent":"2.66","id":"7150"},{"percent":"2.65","id":"7034"},{"percent":"2.64","id":"3336"},{"percent":"2.59","id":"6950"},{"percent":"2.54","id":"8685"},{"percent":"2.48","id":"8500"},{"percent":"2.44","id":"8339"},{"percent":"2.38","id":"0507"},{"percent":"2.35","id":"8074"},{"percent":"2.34","id":"7883"},{"percent":"2.27","id":"8667"},{"percent":"2.21","id":"8742"},{"percent":"2.18","id":"0502"},{"percent":"2.15","id":"7740"},{"percent":"2.12","id":"7472"},{"percent":"2.11","id":"3298"},{"percent":"2.02","id":"9008"},{"percent":"2.01","id":"6743"},{"percent":"2.01","id":"6643"}]},"encoding":"ISO-8859-1"}
```

Now, when I launch the app and click on the "Get JSON" button the I get "Success[]" instead of "Success -Ex: Data...-" and no list appears with the data, like before.

What should I do to make this work for the new URL?

Here is the code I am using:

**MyFantasyLeagueActivity.java**

```
public final static String BaseUrl="http://football.myfantasyleague.com/"; 

ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> deptList=new ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD>();

private class GetDeptAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Hashtable<String,String>,Void,String>{

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String,String>... params) {
       Hashtable ht=params[0];

       String json=HelperHttp.getJSONResponseFromURL(BaseUrl+"2007/export?TYPE=topAdds&W=12&JSON=1", ht);
       if(json!=null) parseJsonString(deptList,json);
       else{
        return "Invalid Company Id";
       }
       return "SUCCESS";
      }

      protected void parseJsonString(ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> deptList,String json){
          try {
               JSONArray array=new JSONArray(json);
               for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                JSONObject j=array.getJSONObject(i);
                DEPT_HOLD d=new DEPT_HOLD();
                d.one=j.optString("percent","");
                d.two=j.optString("id","");
                deptList.add(d);
               }

              } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }

      } 


      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result){

          if(result=="SUCCESS")
          {
           Toast.makeText(MyFantasyLeagueActivity.this, "Success"+deptList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           DeptArrayAdapter adapter=new DeptArrayAdapter(MyFantasyLeagueActivity.this,R.id.text1,deptList);
           ListView listv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
           listv.setAdapter(adapter);
          }
          else{}
      }

}
```

I'm sure that the solution is obvious and I'll feel stupid, but I spent too much time looking at this. I need a new set of eyes to help me figure out what's going on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The one in the tutorial is just a simple JSON array. But yours is little complex than that. So, I think you might want to check out your JSON parser.hard code this json string in your code and check if you get it parsed.

Comment: Post only relevant data, not your whole project. The json parser bit should be enough if you receive the correct data (you did check for that, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original JSON has an array at the top level, but your new JSON is an object.  So in your `parseJsonString` method, you first need to create a `JSONObject` out of the data.  Then you need to drill into the `topAdds` and `player` properties to get to the array of percent/id pairs.  Without error checking:

```
protected void parseJsonString(ArrayList<DEPT_HOLD> deptList,String json){
    try {
        JSONObject top = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject topAdds = (JSONObject) top.get("topAdds");
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) topAdds.get("player");

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject j = array.getJSONObject(i);
            DEPT_HOLD d = new DEPT_HOLD();
            d.one = j.optString("percent","");
            d.two = j.optString("id","");
            deptList.add(d);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```